# Saving class with tensorflow model

Tags: tensorflow

Suppose I have an encapsulated in class tensorflow model, which defined in similar way:

```
class Model:
    def __init__(self, ...):
        self.graph = tf.Graph()
        self.sess = tf.Session(graph=self.graph)

        <some flags, numbers, numpy arrays>
        <some tf variables and placeholders>
        <tf initialization>
```

What is best-practices to save and restore this model with all attributes?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether there's any best practices. But here is one to watch out while using `simple-save`:

**Iterator and dataset:**

Be careful about the iterator on dataset as iterator may not be restored from saved graph. Since it may init a new one when restoring.

**Don't:**

```
# Save
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features, labels))
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
<iterator get next>

# Restore
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features, labels))
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
```

**Do:**

```
# Save
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features, labels))
iterator = tf.data.Iterator.from_structure(dataset.output_types, dataset.output_shapes)
dataset_init_op = iterator.make_initializer(dataset, name='dataset_initializer')

# Resotre
dataset_init_op = graph.get_operation_by_name('dataset_initializer')
```

Feel free to add points below.